# Arel with multiple select to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

How can I get the result of an Arel query with multiple select as a hash?

Consider the following:

```
    users = User.arel_table 
    posts = Post.arel_table  # posts.uploader_id -> users.id

    User
      .left_joins(:posts)
      .select(
        users[Arel.star].as("user"),
        posts[Arel.star].count.as("total_post_count")
      )
      .group(users[:id])
      .order(
        :total_post_count
      )
```

The result for this is an array of ActiveRecord User objects that have the attribute "total_post_count" accessible in them. Instead what I want is a hash or a structure that has user, total_post_count etc as separate object, so for example:

```
[{"user" => User1, "total_post_count" => 10, ...}]
```

Even returning the results as tuples would be good enough because that way I could just do a map to sort them into a structure. But I'm stumped right now as I can't get arel to return anything other than an array of Users.

Comment: IIRC, you should be able to call `map(&:attributes)` on those objects to get all the extra fields from the query as well. They are not displayed by default `inspect`

Comment: That map ends up being called on the User model itself. I don't want those attributes to end up in the user model in the first poinit.

Comment: @ihatenginx what you are asking for is not how ActiveRecord works. The only way to get your desired result without the virtual attribute `User#total_post_count` would be to count them separately e.g. `User.eager_load(:posts).map {|user| {"user" => user, "total_post_count" => user.posts.size}}`. You may be able to use `in_batches` and `flat_map` to lessen the memory load but either way this is much less efficient than your current design.

Comment: @ihatenginx - That's not how attributes work on ActiveRecord. `attributes` are a collection of fields returned by the query and have very little to do with `columns`. If you modify your query includes additioanl field, they should be included when you call `attributes`. This does not require any additional attributes defined on the model itself. Honestly, IMO, this should eb treated as AR bug